# Removing uneditable text from studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Stupid question. I just started trying to use studio code to write in java and realized that after compiling that x: (uneditable) appears before the string. Seems like a setting that i should change, how could i remove it?

compiled my first program and expected no new text to appear on my code.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYLJZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The "uneditable" text that appears before your strings in Studio Code is called a "read-only" indicator, and it is displayed by default to indicate that the text is not editable. This can be useful when working with code that is generated by a compiler or interpreter, as it helps you to distinguish between editable and uneditable code.

To remove the read-only indicator from your code, you can do the following:

Open the Settings editor in Studio Code by going to the File menu and selecting Preferences > Settings.

In the Settings editor, search for the **"editor.rulers"** setting.

Set the **"editor.rulers"** setting to an empty array, like this:

```
"editor.rulers": []
```

Save your changes by clicking on the "Save" button in the top-right corner of the Settings editor.
After completing these steps, the read-only indicators should no longer appear in your code.

Please note that disabling the read-only indicators may make it more difficult to distinguish between editable and uneditable code. You may want to consider leaving this feature enabled, and instead using a different color or font style for the read-only indicators to make them more noticeable.

Comment: By the way i can still see the read-only indicator after doing this. I haven't found a solution to this.